# Why does e.name not return the same value as e().name? Not the event object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've basically been playing around with some JavaScript chaining and was looking at the jQuery source trying to understand how they do some things. I know they have different functions on their global `$` than they do on `$()`, but I thought some were the same?

I was also wondering if I could get some help understanding what's going on. Not sure what other use cases chaining would have, but I'd love to understand the internals a little bit better.

Here is my code (It now works properly look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353440/1165441) for clarification:

```
/*
Chaining stuff
*/

var e = function() {
    return new e.ext.init();
};

e.ext = {
    _name: 'test',
    init: function() {
        console.log('init');
        return this;
    },
    chainA: function() {
        console.log('chainA');
        return this;
    },
    chainB: function() {
        console.log('chainB');
        return this;
    }
};

/*
* Fix the value of `this` in `e.ext.init
* by setting its prototype to the value
* of `e.ext`
*/
e.ext.init.prototype = e.ext;

// e and e() can have the same properties if we loop through e.ext and add them
for(var prop in e.ext) {   
    e[prop] = e.ext[prop];
}

// log output
console.log('-- logging chaining demo --\n');
console.log(e._name);
e.chainA().chainB();

console.log('\n');
console.log(e()._name);
e().chainA().chainB();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edhedges/EM6Ck/

Edit: How is this off topic? Also why do the functions work from `e` like `e.chainA()` works the same as `e().chainA()`?

Comment: Please include your code *in* the question. If JSFiddle were to go down, the question wouldn't be nearly as valuable!

Comment: You should have named the title different, because *everybody* thinks you mean the `e`vent object. ;)

Comment: e.name is a property of the object e, while e().name is calling the name property on the object returned by the e() function.

Comment: This question has less to do with jQuery than a fundamental understanding of how object-oriented programming works. Short answer: the function `e` is an object, and executing the function `e()` *returns* a completely different object -- rather like the difference between a soufflé recipe and the actual soufflé.

Comment: @Anon your comment is actually wrong take a look at the answer to find out what was actually going on.

Comment: @Blazemonger I just included jQuery as a tag because I am using ideas from the jQuery source and thought it was relevant. Also take a look at the answer to find out the real reason it wasn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `e` is a function, not an object. So your choking point is here:

```
for(var prop in e.ext) {   
    e[prop] = e.ext[prop];
}
```

I add `console.log(e[prop]);` after each assignment, and get `empty string` and three `function()` result;

Moreover, when i call `e['chainA']()` i get `chainA` response. So i guess you actually can assign other functions like that, making some form of composition. But it won't work with anything else.

Actually `Javascript: The Definitive Guide` brings this example up:

```
uniqueInteger.counter = 0;
// This function returns a different integer each time it is called.
// It uses a property of itself to remember the next value to be returned.
function uniqueInteger() {
   return uniqueInteger.counter++;    
}
```

and it works!

```
console.log(uniqueInteger()); //0
console.log(uniqueInteger()); //1
console.log(uniqueInteger.counter); //2
```

It works even when variable is referenced as array literal too.
So it seems the real reason behind this weird behavior is somewhere else.

I'm dumb. Here's your answer (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)):

```
 Function.name
    The name of the function.
```

So you're just trying to override inner property of a `Function` object, which, i guess, won't work that way. It's an empty string because `e` is an anonymous function, which makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Exactly! I don't understand why you can augment a function, but not a property.

Comment: I guess it's just one of those mysteries of the universe which aren't meant to be solved by mortals.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that I could augment a differently named property onto my `var e` like `e.nameTwo = 'testTwo'` and that would work fine. I'm thinking it's something about how the `for...in` is augmenting the properties onto `e`, but I want to know why!

Comment: Bingo! Found a proper answer.

Comment: Wow good find! I'm glad it was something trivial because I was going crazy not understanding.

Comment: @TwiStar Where can I see, that the function is actually anonymous (or did you talk prophetic while finding the mysteries out;)? When I do `console.log(e instanceof Function)` it returns `true`. But where can I see in the console, that `e`'s `name` is actually empty?

Comment: `console.log(e.name)`. Also, its declaration `var e = function()` - this syntax creates anonymous function, instead of `function e()`.

Comment: Ok, I did not get the `e`'s function name, but when I did `console.log(new e())` I could see the empty name of e.g. `chainA` (You know with the arrows and such;). That's enough, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

using e() creates the object while simply using e only returns the function that creates the object in a nutshell.

Comment: I understand that much, but in my loop I'm augmenting properties onto `e` and making calls to functions that are appended to `e` works fine, but the actual prop doesn't have a value.